# Razor view with inline stylesheet and media query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an .cshtml page that requires some basic inline styling for print only.
I was going to use the `@media print` media query, however, this being an cshtml page, it breaks my page. Is there any way to get around this?

It's the `@` symbol in `@media print` that is breaking it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can double the `@` if you want to print a literal `@` character in the output.

```
<style>
    @@media print {
       ...
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

p.s.w.g is absolutely correct. To understand why the @ symbol is causing an issue in your .cshtml file I suggest you research Razor View Engine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine which happens to start when you type @ in your .cshtml page. Simply put it's an HTML rendering mechanism that generates HTML for you. It is usually used when you want to display data contained in your models =]